# Converting a object into a List<object> C#

Tags: c#, types, casting

I have a method as such:

```
 if (value != null && value.GetType().IsGenericType &&
                value.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
            {
                SetDropDownList(value)
            }
```

The if statement is applied to a list that can contain lists.
Now when it finds a list I send it to the method SetDropDownList().
This method signature looks like this:

```
public void SetDropDownList(object list)
        {
            
        }
```

Now my question is, is it possible to check what the list contains and cast it as that type.
So say its a list of strings (List).
can I do something like

```
{
var listType = list.GetType();
List<listType> mylist = new List<listType>();
}
```

Now i know this code would never work but i just want you to get some idea of what i am trying to do.
Thx

Comment: No, you can't use generic type object like that. Personnaly I used reflection to run generic method, specially `method.MakeGenericMethod(typeObject)`

Comment: It's probably worth noting that if you need to do this, then your code may be in need of a refactor. Generally seeing things like this is a code smell.

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the object is an `IEnumerable`.

For example:

```
object obj = new List<string>();

if(obj is IEnumerable list)
    foreach(var item in list)
        Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

If the passed in list *IS* a type, we can use type pattern matching to simplify this sort of logic, especially if there are multiple known or expected types:

```
public void SetDropDownList(object list)
{
    if (list is List<listType> typedList)
    {
        // TODO: do something with this typed list
        Console.WriteLine(typedList.Count());
    }
    else if (list is IEnumerable genericList)
    {
        // this is a catchall for enumerable sources, again using pattern matching to simplify the syntax
        foreach(var item in genericList)
        {
            // deal with the item
            Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
        }
    }
    else
        throw new NotImplementedException("list type not recognised: " + list.GetType().Name);
}
```